# javascript video tag source change

Tags: javascript, video

I wrote the below script tag to play a shortened 10s video loop for smaller devices.  When in Firefox and in responsive design mode and in a screen size less that 700px - this code executes with no issues, however once deployed to the server and actually viewing on my iPhone the video does not play.  Can you advise why this might be happening ?

```
<script>
const mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width:700px)" );
if (mq.matches) {
    let video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.setAttribute("src", "./assets/Mobile_Background.mp4");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your video has no sound (mobile O.S don't usually autoplay videos with sound). You can set `muted` in your video tag attributes to avoid using a different (non-audio) file.

You can try as:

```
<script>

const mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width:700px)" );
if (mq.matches) 
{
    let video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.setAttribute('autoplay','');
    video.setAttribute('muted','');
    video.setAttribute('loop','');
    video.setAttribute('playsInline','');
    video.setAttribute("src", "./assets/Mobile_Background.mp4");
}

</script>
```

If still failing...

- Try adding `true` to the attributes shown above. Example: `('muted','true');`.
- Check video path. Maybe you want `assets/`? (without dot-slash like `./assets/`).
- Use a real full path to video file for testing / checking. Example [video link](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4).